# WordPress multi site images and files not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, permissions, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite Subfolder site where all of the images and css files are throwing a 404. I can access the file if I take out the multisite slug in the path like this:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2019/08/18248332854553431489.png`

But it doesn't work if the multi-site slug is in the url 
`https://example.com/multi-site-slug/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2019/08/18248332854553431489.png`

I've tried several different .htaccess configurations to try and get this to work but to no avail.

Here's how the .htaccess file is right now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I have tried several methods things for uploaded files including:

`RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]`

..and this (Where N = the site number like 11):

`RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?siteN/files/(.+) wp-content/blogs.dir/N/files/$2 [L]`

Also, files and images are working fine for the main site.

**UPDATE**

I've checked my NGINX error log and noticed I'm getting the following error:

`[error] 27521#0: *489567 open() "/home/example/public_html/multi-site-slug/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2019/08/123418248332854553431489.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XXX.XX.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET /multi-site-slug/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2019/08/123418248332854553431489.png HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have enabled CGI and FastCGI support. I spent two days debugging issues with WPMS and until I decided to fully troubleshoot.

- I made a copy of my site (a simple mv command will do). Don't delete the DB
- I created a fresh copy of my site
- Compared it with another subdomain that worked out of the box and matched the settings

Turned out, I switched off CGI support, probably for performance at some point.